# JS Reset Web Storage

Tags: javascript, html

I got trouble with my webstorage, I'm trying to explain my best. I have 2 different pages.

Page 1 (Index ): Is the Index,, this is where you can input results into the searchbar. When pressing the button "filter' (Its filters names) and redirects you to a new page, page 2.

Page 2 (Seachresults): Is where the searchbar, filter AND the (filterd) search-results are.

I do this by using Local web storage.

The problem I'm having follow: When I get redirected to page 2 and I'm entering a new search result in the searchbar and click filter nothing happens, It shows the previews filters results. I think it

This is the code from Page 1 (Index, "run'doesnt work properly because of localwebstorage but you will get an idea)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="autocomplete"  placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<button onclick="mystorage(); location.href = './searchresults.html';">Filter</button>
<hr>
<script>
// Check browser support
function mystorage() {
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", document.getElementById("autocomplete").value);
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code from Page 2 (Seachresults)

```
<body onload="mystorage(),myauto(), myfilter();">
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" value="" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<p>
Search results for  "<span id="result"></span>"
</p>
<button onclick="mystorage()"> Filter </button>
<hr>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
function myauto() {
    document.getElementById("autocomplete").value = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
}
function mystorage() {
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else if (typeof(Storage) == "undefined") {

}
else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
}
function myfilter() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The only thing you have the button click doing on the second page is calling `mystorage` which just changes what's in session storage and nothing else. What's the expected behavior? Were you wanting to re-run `myfilter`? You'll just need to call that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter button in the second page is calling mystorage() which takes data from the storage and displays it, that's all, i think you want to assign `myfilter()` to the filter button so it get's the value you entered and filters it.

`<button onclick="myfilter()"> Filter </button>`

To call `myfilter()` which takes the input value, not the one in the storage that came from the first page.

```
function myfilter() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```